# Required Minimum Distribution Tax Rates

Tags: united-states, 401k, capital-gains-tax, rmd

As I understand it, if one sells Apple Stock in a 401K and takes the cash proceeds as RMD, then it is taxed as [ordinary income and not capital gains](https://personal-finance.extension.org/do-i-have-to-pay-capital-gain-taxes-on-my-required-minimum-distribution-rmd/).

If instead the stock was not sold and taken out of the 401K put in a IRA (as a stock), would the owner enjoy [capital gains](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/personal-finance/101515/comparing-longterm-vs-shortterm-capital-gain-tax-rates.asp) rate of instead?  Assume that the Apple Stock is held long term per capital gains definintion.

Comment: Clarification: An IRA has the same tax treatment as a 401(k). Moving assets from a 401(k) to an IRA (assuming the Traditional vs. Roth designation for both is the same) would be a rollover, not a distribution, and would not be taxable. You would still need to take an RMD (either from the IRA, 401(k), or both).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification,  I am wondering if there is a pathway that would enables retirees to leverage favorable capital gains taxation in any manner?

Comment: No.  Withdrawals from an IRA or 401(k) are taxed as ordinary income unless they are from nondeductible contributions.  This is independent of whether it was an RMD or you just decided to withdraw the money.  The good news on these accounts is you pay no taxes along the way, even if you sell one stock and buy another.  The bad news is that if you buy one stock and hold it forever the gain is taxed as regular income.  If you knew which stocks would skyrocket and you would hold them forever, you should buy them in a taxable account to get the capital gains treatment.

Answer (score 13):

Withdrawals from either a 401(k) or an IRA are treated as normal income, not as capital gains. So transferring from your 401(k) to an IRA would make no difference tax-wise.

401(k)s and IRAs are tax-*deferred* accounts. You received a tax break when you put the money in that purchased the stock, and when you take it out, you pay tax on the full amount withdrawn, not just the gain.

Similarly, you can't sell securities that have lost money and count it as a capital loss - you pay tax on the amount that was taken out, whether it came from winners or losers.

This is opposed to a non-retirement investment account where you buy stock with "after-tax" funds, thus you only pay tax on the *gain* to avoid getting double-taxed.

Comment: Just a minor clarification. Some IRA custodians (and perhaps some 401(k) administrators too?) allow distributions of stock (instead of cash) to the IRA owner, but the _tax treatment_ is as if the stock was sold _inside_ the IRA (at the closing price of the day of the distribution) and the proceeds distributed as cash and the recipient promptly  bought the same shares (at the closing price), all this without there being an actual sale of the shares at all (and thus no brokerage fees etc). And the "cash" taken as a distribution is taxed as ordinary income, not as capital gains.

Comment: Non-retirement accounts are effectively double taxed on the gains (whereas retirement accounts (traditional or roth) are single taxed, that's why retirement accounts are good). Example assuming 40% income tax and 30% capital gains tax, and $10: You pay $4 income tax, then invest $6, it triples over time to $18 and you pay $12*.3 = $3.6 capital gains tax, for a final result of $14.4. No tax would mean you would have $30. A traditional account would mean it becomes $30 then you pay $12 taxes so you have $18. A roth account would mean $6 after tax becomes $18. (Roth and traditional end the same.)

Comment: Also, retirees typically have lower income (and thus lower income tax rates), so deferring taxes helps there, too.